# Bash script to scp newest file in a directory on a remote server

Tags: bash, cron, backup, scp, database-backups

Ok so I kinda know how to do this locally with a find then cp command, but don't know how to do the same remotely with scp.

So know this:

```
scp -vp me@server:/target/location/ /destination/dir/.
```

That target directory is going to be full of database backups, how can I tell it to find the latest backup, and scp that locally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
remote_dir=/what/ever
dst=remote-system.host.name.com
scp $dst:`ssh $dst ls -1td $remote_dir/\* | head -1` /tmp/lastmod
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a script on the remote side that uses `find` to find it and then `cat` to send it to stdout, then run:

```
ssh me@server runscript.sh > localcopy
```

Comment: So I make something like this remotely: ls -t | head -1 | cat stdout then i execute it locally with ssh me@server runscript.sh > localcopy ... then cat localcopy into a variable that gets used for the file name?

Comment: No. The script looks like: `cat "$(ls -t | head -n 1)"`, and then localcopy will have the file's contents.

Comment: Humm seems no need for the cat, the >> does the output. so ls -t /var/backup| head -n 1

Comment: That will print just the filename. Why not just get the file in the first place?

Comment: the remote server is always making new backups so the file names change constantly. I need the latest one. I ended up setting a variable for the file name like this:
remote_backup=`ssh $dst ls -1td $remote_dir/\* | head -1| cut -d/ -f6`
I then just called in in the following:scp $dst:$remote_dir/$remote_backup $target

Comment: So what? The script returns the contents of the latest file. You don't even *need* to use `scp`.